# Load data from CSV into OrientDB with etl raising java error

Tags: java, csv, orientdb

I am new to orientdb and tried to load data from CSV with the etl tool. Not sure if I made any silly mistake. What I need is to link one column to another from each individual row. Thanks for the help.

my JSON file is listed below:

```
{
  "config": {
    "log": "debug"
  },
  "source" : {
    "file": { "path":"./test.csv"}
  },
  "extractor": { "row": {} },
  "transformers": [
    { "csv": { "separator": ",",
               "columnsOnFirstLine":true,
               "columns":["servicename", "deviceid","blazeid","ip"] } },
    { "vertex": { "skipDuplicates":true, "class": "loginfo" } },
    { "merge": { "joinFieldName":"blazeid", "lookup":"loginfo.blazeid" } },
    { "edge": {
       "class": "Device",
       "joinFieldName": "deviceid",
       "edgeFields": { "ip": "${input.ip}" },
       "lookup": "loginfo.blazeid",
       "unresolvedLinkAction": "CREATE"
      }
    },
  ],
  "loader": {
    "orientdb": {
       "dbURL": "plocal:../orientdb-3.0.22/databases/devicedb",
       "dbType":"graph","dbAutoCreate":true,
       "serverUser":"root", "serverPassword":"root",
       "indexes":[],"standardElementConstraints":true,"dbUser":"root",
       "useLightweightEdges":false,"dbAutoDropIfExists":true,
       "dbPassword":"root","dbAutoCreateProperties":false,
       "wal": false,
       "batchCommit": 1000,
       "tx": true,
       "txUseLog": false,
       "useLightweightEdges" : true,
       "classes": [
         {"name": "loginfo", "extends": "V"},
         {"name": "Device", "extends": "E"}
       ]
    }
  }
}
```

error msg shows "Transformer 'csv' not found".

```
OrientDB etl v.3.0.22 - Veloce (build 8afc634a2ea9c351898ae57dee8d739ff4851252, branch 3.0.x) https://www.orientdb.com
Exception in thread "main" com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OConfigurationException: Error on creating ETL processor
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessorConfigurator.parse(OETLProcessorConfigurator.java:153)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessorConfigurator.parseConfigAndParameters(OETLProcessorConfigurator.java:92)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessor.main(OETLProcessor.java:116)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Transformer 'csv' not found
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLComponentFactory.getTransformer(OETLComponentFactory.java:136)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessorConfigurator.configureTransformers(OETLProcessorConfigurator.java:184)
        at com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessorConfigurator.parse(OETLProcessorConfigurator.java:131)
```

Comment: Try to provide an hard link to the csv to see append again.

Comment: Can you try using an absolute path for the source file rather than a relative path?